# Deformation to a normal cone for a holomorphically symplectic manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic, hyperkaehler

Let $X$ be a subvariety in $M$. 
["Deformation to the normal cone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_to_the_normal_cone)
is a holomorphic deformation of a neighbourhood
of $X$ in $M$ over the disk such that its central fiber
is the total space of the normal bundle $NX$, and
the rest of the fibers are $M$.

I want to have a holomorphically symplectic version of this
statement. The following conjecture seems to be true; I
think I have a proof (ugly), but I am afraid it's already
known.

Let $(M, \Omega)$ be a holomorphically
symplectic manifold, and  $X\subset M$
a compact holomorphic Lagrangian subvariety.
Assume that $M$  admits a proper, birational map
which contracts $X$. Then there exists
a smooth, holomorphic deformation
of a neighbourhood of $X$ in $M$
over the disk $\Delta$, such that
its central fiber is biholomorphic to
a neighbourhood of $X$ in $T^*X$,
the rest of the fibers are
biholomorphic to a neighbourhood of $X$ in $M$,
and the holomorphic symplectic form on
$T^*X$ can be smoothly extended to the
holomorphic symplectic form on the
rest of the fibers.

This statement is provably false for some other holomorphic Lagrangian
subvarieties, such as a smooth fiber in a sufficiently generic
proper holomorphically Lagrangian fibration. I know there are MO
users who know the subject better than me, any help will be highly
appreciated.